# how to set authentication in wsdl

Tags: php, web-services

please help me how to set authentication for wsdl iam new to webservices. I set apache authentication for this file but when client is accessing WSDL is not loading. Iam not able to set authentication
below is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions  name="bsci" targetNamespace="urn:bsci" xmlns:tns="urn:bsci"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/">

 <types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://bsci.local/">

    <s:element name="createinvoiceaccount">
       <s:complexType>
         <s:sequence>
           <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MemberesInfo" type="tns:InvoiceInfo"/>
         </s:sequence>
       </s:complexType>
     </s:element>
    <s:complexType name="InvoiceInfo">
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MemberName" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="MemCode" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="InvoiceNumber" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="InvoiceOnDate" type="s:date"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="InvoiceAmount" type="s:double"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="InvoiceDueDate" type="s:date"/>
     </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>

    </s:schema>
 </types>


  <message name="createinvoiceaccount">
    <part name="userdata" type="tns:array" />
  </message>

  <message name="createinvoiceaccountResponse">
    <part name="return" type="tns:string" />
  </message>

  <portType name="createinvoiceaccountPort">
    <operation name="createinvoiceaccount">
      <input message="tns:createinvoiceaccount" />
      <output message="tns:createinvoiceaccountResponse" />
    </operation>
  </portType>

  <binding name="createinvoiceaccountBinding" type="tns:createinvoiceaccountPort">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
      <operation name="createinvoiceaccount">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:createinvoiceaccountAction" />
        <input>
          <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:createinvoiceaccount" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </input>
        <output>
          <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:createinvoiceaccount" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </output>
      </operation>
  </binding>

  <service name="createinvoiceaccountService">
    <port name="createinvoiceaccountPort" binding="tns:createinvoiceaccountBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://bsci.local/webservices/bobservice/createinvoiceaccount" />
    </port>
  </service>

</definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

try http://username:password@bsci.local/webservices/bobservice/createinvoiceaccount